# Sum and Product of Sums of Measures

Tags: probability, general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and $(C,\mathcal{C},\nu)$ be  two measure spaces with sum finite measures $(\mu(X)>0,\nu(C)>0$). Define the product measure of $\mu,\nu$ on $(X\times C, \mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{C})$ by

$$\mu\otimes\nu(G)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_n\otimes \nu_m(G)$$

Where $\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_n$ and $\nu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\nu_n$ ($\mu_n,\nu_n>0, n \in \mathbb{N}$). Let $\mu=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_n^*$ be another partition of $\mu$ in finite measures measures.

Show that

$$\mu\otimes\nu(G)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\mu_n^*\otimes \nu_m(G), \quad G\in\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{C}$$

---

I have shown that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int 1_A(x)d\mu_n(x)=\mu(A)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int 1_A(x)d\mu_n^*(x)$$

and I have shown Tonelli-Fubini (double integral iteration) where the function is now just the indicator, i.e $f=1_A$. From this how does the result follow?

Comment: Fixed indexing error.

Comment: What $\mu_n^*$ mean?

Comment: @Shiva Sorry I will add it now!

Comment: it is just another way of defining $\mu$ from another partition of measures.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. Looks like you're almost there. You should consider $$\int_{X \times C} 1_A(x) 1_B(y) \mu \otimes \nu\left(dxdy\right), \quad A \in \mathcal{A}, B \in \mathcal{C}.$$ A clever rewriting of this integral using the first representation of $\mu \otimes \nu$ (hint: try to write it as the product of two sums) followed by applying what you have already found will give you the desired result.

Comment: @Shiva Thanks for your comment! I am not sure why I am considering the integral proposed by you. I have been dwelling on your hint but not sure on what you mean by the product of two sums; wouldn't the expression become 2 integrals that we can iterate with Fubini? (furthermore the product would be defined as a sum and not the integral?) (and the notation for the differential is the same as $d(\mu \otimes \nu)$, right?

Comment: @Shiva is it the integral induced by the product measure? but how does that correlate to the definition

Comment: Yes, it's the integral with respect to the product measure. $\int_{X \times C} 1_A(x) 1_B(y) \mu \otimes \nu\left(dxdy\right)$ is the same as $ \mu \otimes \nu\left(dxdy\right)\left(A\times B\right)$. Also yes $\mu \otimes \nu\left(dxdy\right) = d\left(\mu \otimes \nu\right)$ and the notation is useful for being explicit about which variable we are integrating with respect to.

Comment: I see. I just don't see how to finish it from this point on after figuring the previous results out. I have spend hours on it but don't see how the 'product of sums' and forward part to make sense. I should have the given result now but the last step is a major annoyance. @Shiva

Comment: Okay apologies that my hint was too clear. I put an answer down below

Answer (score 1):

Let $A \in \mathcal{A}$ and $B \in \mathcal{C}$. Applying Fubini we get,
\begin{gather}
\int_{X\times C} 1_A(x)1_B(y)\; \mu \otimes \nu\left(dxdy\right) = \sum_{n,m = 1}^\infty \int_{X\times C} 1_A(x)1_B(y)\; \mu_n \otimes \nu_m\left(dxdy\right) = \sum_{n,m = 1}^\infty \left(\int_X 1_A d\mu_n\right)\left(\int_C 1_B d\nu_m\right).
\end{gather}
The above is the product of two infinite sums, $$\sum_{n,m = 1}^\infty \left(\int_X 1_A d\mu_n\right)\left(\int_C 1_B d\nu_m\right) = \left(\sum_{n =1}^\infty \int_X 1_A d\mu_n\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\int_C 1_B d\nu_m\right)$$
Then substituting in the alternative representation of $\mu$, we have that the above equals
$$\left(\sum_{n =1}^\infty \int_X 1_A d\mu_n^*\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\int_C 1_B d\nu_m\right) = \sum_{n,m = 1}^\infty \int_{X\times C} 1_A(x)1_B(y)\; \mu^*_n \otimes \nu_m\left(dxdy\right).$$
Now let $\mathcal{H}$ be the set of bounded $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{C}$-measurable functions such that their integrals with respect to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_n\otimes \nu_m$ and with respect to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^*_n\otimes \nu_m$
$$\mathcal{H} = \left\{f:X\times C \to \mathbb{R} \text{ bounded and measurable} : \int_{X\times C} f d\left(\mu\otimes \nu\right) = \int_{X\times C} f d\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^*_n\otimes \nu_m \right)\right\}. $$

From the above argument we know that $\mathcal{H}$ contains functions of the form $f:X\times C \to \mathbb{R}, \;(x,y) \mapsto 1_A(x)1_B(y)$. It is clear that $\mathcal{H}$ is a vector space. Furthermore by monotone convergence, if a function $f$ is the increasing limit of functions in $\mathcal{H}$ then $f\in \mathcal{H}$. By [monotone class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Monotone_class_theorem_for_functions) and the definition of the product sigma algebra, $\mathcal{H}$ contains all bounded $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{C}$-measurable functions, which give the desired result.

Comment: I follow you all the way to "now let". I do not see where we show the equality $\mu\otimes\nu(G)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\mu_n^*\otimes \nu_m(G), \quad G\in\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{C}$. We have not dealt with vector spaces in terms of measure theory as well; the argument seems really complex.

Comment: We have not had $\pi$-systems yet as well, unfortunately.

Comment: Perhaps. The fact that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are only s-finite makes things a bit delicate. Everything before "now let" just shows that $mu\otimes \nu$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^*_n\otimes \nu_m$ agree on the set of rectangles $\left\{A\times B : A\in \mathcal{A}, B\in \mathcal{C}\right\}$, then use this to show that the two measure do in fact coincide on $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{C}$. Usually, this is done by invoking some form of the monotone class theorem and in this case, the hypotheses functional version seemed easier to verify.

Comment: Also for monotone class, we need that $\mathcal{H}$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, I only said that $\mathcal{H}$ was a vector space for brevity.

Comment: I see. But still, I do not see where the argument for the equality that I want to show is done within the last text. Can this be  written out mathimatically when we show the equality in question?

Comment: The monotone class theorem lets us conclude that the $$\int_{X\times C} f d\left(\mu\otimes \nu\right) = \int_{X\times C} f d\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^*_n\otimes \nu_m
\right)$$ for all bounded and measurable $f$, since $\mathcal{H}$ is exactly the set of functions for which the above equality holds. Taking $f = 1_G$, $G\in \mathcal{A}\otimes\mathcal{C}$, then gives that $$\mu\otimes \nu(G) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu^*_n\otimes \nu_m (G).$$

Comment: "Multiplying" the first equality by $\nu$ would only give that the two representations agree on the rectangles. I don't know any uniqueness theorems for s-finite measure (I know there is if the measures were $\sigma$-finite). What have you seen in your class?

Comment: As for $\mathcal{H}$, we need three hypotheses to apply monotone class: (1)That there exists a collection of sets, $\mathcal{S}$, closed under intersection, containing the whole space, and which generate the sigma-algebra on said space such that $\left\{1_S : S\in \mathcal{S}\right\} \subset \mathcal{H}$; (2) for if $f,g \in \mathcal{H}$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $af + bg \in \mathcal{H}$; (3) $\mathcal{H}$ is closed under bounded increasing limits. The calculation showing that (...)

Comment: (...) $\left(\sum_{n =1}^\infty \int_X 1_A d\mu_n^*\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^\infty\int_C 1_B d\nu_m\right) = \sum_{n,m = 1}^\infty \int_{X\times C} 1_A(x)1_B(y)\; \mu^*_n \otimes \nu_m\left(dxdy\right)$ shows that the first point is verified. Without it the second part could be vacuously true. Oh also I should have be more explicit about this earlier but since we need $\mathcal{S}$ to be closed under intersection we should take it to be the set of finite unions of sets of the form $A\times B$ $A\in \mathcal{A}, B\in \mathcal{C}$.